# NodeJS - Firebase - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'where')

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, es6-modules, ecma

I have a function which should query the *Firestore*. It looks like this

```
class TournamentParticipationDataAccessService {
  
    setProperties() {
       this.tournamentParticipationRef = database.collection('/tournamentParticipation')
    }

   checkIfTournamentHasReachedParticipationNumber(tournamentObject) {    

    this.tournamentParticipationRef.where("tournamentId", "==", tournamentObject.objectID).where("round", "==", tournamentObject.currentRound)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
    
         // MAGIC

     }  
   ..
}
```

It complains about that **where** statement. The **database** variable is defined in a different file:

```
firebase = require('firebase');
firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
..
database = firebase.firestore();
```

My index.js file where the variables from top are defined doesn't contain any classes. Just a plain script.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a more verbose version of your code, as well as any error message/debug logs you are getting?